# OpenSSL Handshake failed, point is not on curve

Tags: tls, openssl, ecc

When I try to connect a SSL/TLS client (OpenSSL 1.0.0d) to an SSL/TLS server (OpenSSL 1.0.2), sometimes the handshake fails and errors with `point is not on curve`, and `decryption failed or bad record mac` on the server.

I'm electronic engineer and newbie to SSL/TLS but I understand from the error that the Certificate Elliptic Curve (EC) test failed, but why does handshaking fail arbitrarily?

How can I resolve this problem?

**Update:**

I inspected the packets with Wireshark. The packet counts and packet size for a successful handshake and for a failed one are the same.

The client (openssl 1.0.0d) is on uclinux and the server (openssl 1.0.2) is on 32-bit Windows.

When I match the server and client's platforms and versions (i.e server is using OpenSSL 1.0.0d and running on uclinux), then the SSL handshake always succeeds.

Comment: What does the documentation on OpenSSL say? I feel, that this is more a question of implementation than it is about information security.

Comment: i  google "point is not on curve" but i can't find document on official openssl site (i can find about elliptic curve cryptography) /// i know implementation  may cause of  problem but i find many near question on information security stackexchang

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation either. I had to read the source code, where it is used as part of a sanity test.

Comment: What client to what server?  Are you writing a program that's using the openssl library?  Or you're using the `openssl` cli binaries?

Comment: I'm using openssl for TLS/SSL in voip program (open source sip stack).client is a user agent client (USC) and server is user agent server (uas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after i upgrade openssl 1.0.0d to 1.0.2m , problem resolved (i test up to 30 time)!
i think problem related to my platform thanks again from Baal-zebub and Tom .
i'm using Linux c6x (uclinux for c6000 TI dsp)
i hope this report useful for other users

Comment: This is why you always update, people.